# Why isn't this code working? HTTP Status 404 – Not Found on jsp and servlet

Tags: java

I am writing a program in java that validate users and if the logged in user was admin he can add another user from registeration form to the database. but when I am going to register someone and press register button it shows me this error.
Here is my code:

```
 index.jsp:
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="loginServlet" method="post">
        <fieldset style="width: 300px">
            <legend> Login to App </legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User ID</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="userpass" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.jsp:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Register form</h3>
        <form method="post" action="Register.jsp">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
        Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>
        Email:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

NewFile.jsp:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Login successful!!! user</h3>
    <h4>
        Hello,
        <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginCheck.java:

```
package com.example.saeid;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoginCheck {
static Boolean isadmin = false;
public static boolean validate(String name, int pass) {
       boolean isValid = false;
       Connection conn = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
        String db_userName = "root";
        String db_Password = "uyhgbv098";
        String db_Name = "my_demo_database";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
       try {
             Class.forName(driver);
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db_Name,db_userName,db_Password);
             ps =conn.prepareStatement
                     ("select * from user_account where username=? and password=?");
                ps.setString(1, name);
                ps.setInt(2, pass);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()) {
                    isValid = true;
                    isadmin = rs.getBoolean("isadmin");
                }


       }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }

public static Boolean admin(){
    return isadmin;
}
}
```

loginservelet.java:

```
package com.example.saeid;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import com.example.saeid.LoginCheck;


public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
        throws ServletException, IOException {  

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

    String n=request.getParameter("username");  
    String p=request.getParameter("userpass");
    int p2 = Integer.parseInt(p);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session!=null)
    session.setAttribute("name", n);

    if(LoginCheck.validate(n, p2)){ 
        if(LoginCheck.admin()){
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }
        else{
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("NewFile.jsp"); 

            rd.forward(request,response); 

        }

    }  
    else{  
        out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");  
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");  
        rd.include(request,response);  
    }  

    out.close();  
}  
}
```

register.java:

```
package com.example.saeid;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String pass1 = request.getParameter("pass");
    int pass = Integer.parseInt(pass1);
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    try{

    //loading drivers for mysql
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//creating connection with the database 
    String db_userName = "root";
    String db_Password = "uyhgbv098";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String db_Name = "my_demo_database";
      Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                 (url+db_Name,db_userName,db_Password);

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
              ("insert into user_acount values(?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setInt(2, pass);
    ps.setString(3, email);

    int i=ps.executeUpdate();

      if(i>0)
      {
        out.println("You are successfully registered");
      }

    }
    catch(Exception se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>FirstHomework</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.saeid.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.saeid.Register</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: please narrow done your problem

Comment: stackoverflow isnt a 'here's my app, fix it' page. please be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You have not given the fully qualified name of `Register` servlet in web.xml:-

```
</servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>  // give the full path 
</servlet>
```

and another thing is that you are storing the password as a String in `register.java` but when you run the query in `Loginservelet` you are setting the password as Int. Please prefer password as a String in both classes.

Comment: i changed the code but got the same error again

Comment: thank you for your help.problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Just as Mayank Sharma said

First, in the web.xml file, you have to specify Register servlet's full path in the servlet-class tag same way you did for LoginServlet class.
Secondly, the value of your register servlet url-pattern tag should be the same value (excluding /) given to the action attribute of the form tag in your welcome.jsp page.
Lastly, take note of Mayank Sharma's second observation.

I must suggest you have to start learning how to develop java web applications using framework. It will help you a lot.

Comment: i changed the code but got the same error again

Comment: thank you for your help.problem solved just have to change Register.jsp to Register without jsp extention in action attribute